# Using a vector image with TVMonogramView

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvuikit

I've looked around and unfortunately there's very little on the web about the latest addition to the tvOS 12.0 which is the TVUIKit and its new controls. I have a UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCells of the following type:

```
import UIKit  
import TVUIKit  

class AirportsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {  

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!  
  var airportView: TVMonogramView!  

  override func awakeFromNib() {  
    airportView = TVMonogramView(frame: self.contentView.frame)  
    airportView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]  
    addSubview(airportView)  
  }  
}
```

I have some images in my assets catalog that are all PDF files and I've naturally checked the "Preserve vector data" and they work absolutely fine when I assign them to my UIImageView of choice with any given size. However, when I assign them to the image property of my TVMonogramView, I get a terrible quality on the images. They seem to have been rendered with a very low resolution.

[image: vector images rendered at a low resolution]

Here's how I use them:

```
if let flag = UIImage(named: countryCode) {  
     cell.airportView.image = flag  
} else {  
     cell.airportView.image = nil  
}
```

How can I fix this behaviour and what is the alternative?

Comment: Why are you using a `TVMonogramView` instead of a `TVLockupView`, when the former should clearly represent a person's image and initials as the documentation clearly states: _"A specialized lockup view that contains a circular image of a person or the person's initials, along with a footer view."_?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Well, **TVLockupView** is the base class and not the one you usually instantiate directly. The TVMonogramView matches my purpose since my images are circular and I need a title and subtitle.